# Why does a function inside a function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, function, object, alert

The output in the code below is `Message 1!` only

```
function alertThenReturn() {
  alert('Message 1!');

  return function () {
    alert('Message 2!');
  };
}
```

The output of the code below (after saving the same function above in a variable) is `Messege1!` `Messege2!`)

```
function alertThenReturn() {
  alert('Message 1!');

  return function () {
    alert('Message 2!');
  };
}

const innerFunction = alertThenReturn();
```

### The expected output for the function in the variable `innerFuciton` is the same as the original function `alertFunction`.
how does the output of the `alertFunction` change just by saving it in another variable

I understand that the `alertThenReturn` doesn't return the second alert but...why does the second alert is returned when the function is stored in a variable (which in this example is `innerFunction`) where the original function and the variable should be identical and the output should be the same

edit: A lot says that after adding the last line the code will not return both alert but it actually return both alerts.

Comment: It doesn't happen unless you call the `innerFunction`.

Comment: _"the function gives both alerts although nothing changed it was just saved in another variable"_ - There won't be _"both alerts"_ unless you have a `innerFunction()` that gets executed right after `const innerFunction = ...`

Comment: That will only show "Message 1!". The return value is the inner function and it's assigned to `innerFunction` but not called.

Comment: yes I understand that it happens after I call the `innerFunction` but why doesn't `alertThanReturn` do the same thing? @GuyIncognito

Comment: You would have to use `alertThenReturn()()` or call it automatically like `return (function(){alert('Message 2!')})()`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you return a function, it doesn't get called automatically. That's the entire point of returning a function so that you can call it later and not immediately.

Comment: isn't the second function part of the first function? so why when calling the `alertThanReturn` the second function isn't called and according to what you say..why don't I do the same thing `()()` to the `innerFunction`

Comment: This whole example makes no sense.

Comment: this example was part of udacity course on oop and not mine so I think it's written by professionals @JavaScript

Comment: @MarcoMaher Please provide a [mcve] of what you don't understand. Adding `const innerFunction = alertThenReturn();` to your code [fires only the first alert not the second one](https://jsfiddle.net/xoaepz9f/).

Comment: @Ivar I edited the question and tried to make my question more direct

Comment: @MarcoMaher It hasn't gotten any clearer to me I'm afraid. You keep mentioning that putting it in a variable changes things. Can you show the version _without_ the variable that works differently? A side-by-side comparison of the two versions and differences would be very useful.

Comment: @Marco Maher: Many users here are professionals.

Comment: @Lain I don't mean any offense but I just said that to let you know that it was written by a professional

Comment: @Ivar I tried to make it clear again just read till (---------)... thanks for your patience for my question.

Comment: @MarcoMaher Your first example is only declaring the function. If I put that code into an editor, [it wont do anything by itself](https://jsfiddle.net/y7fvm9cp/). How are you calling it? And I suspect something similar is missing in the second example.

Comment: I am calling it by `console.log(alertThanReturn())` and in the second example `console.log(InnerFunction())` if that is what you mean by how I am calling it

Comment: @MarcoMaher Yes that makes it more clear. With `const innerFunction = alertThenReturn();` you are not storing the outer function. For that you need to use `const innerFunction = alertThenReturn;`. By adding the parenthesis, you are executing the outer function (and firing the first alert) and the return value (the inner function) is stored in that variable. So when you then call `innerFunction()` the inner function is executed and the second alert is shown.

Comment: thanks! that's what I was looking for.. that's the simple answer to this question. If you want to add this as an answer it will be useful for others and easier to find

Answer (score 0):

`alertThenReturn()` returns function but you are not calling this. If you call `innerFunction`  then you will get second one.

```js
function alertThenReturn() {
  alert('Message 1!');

  return function () {
    alert('Message 2!');
  };
}

const innerFunction = alertThenReturn()();
```

Comment: yes I got your point but that's not my question I want to understand why doesn't the function return both alerts if the main function was called but if it was saved in another variable and calling this variable returns both alerts

Comment: You can't take 2 alerts. Because second one is return you are just returning function which includes alert method.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that just `const innerFunction = alertThenReturn()` would alert twice with the given implementation of `alertThenReturn`.

It will alert once:

```js
function alertThenReturn() {
  alert('Message 1!');

  return function () {
    alert('Message 2!');
  };
}

const innerFunction = alertThenReturn()
```

To alert twice, you need to call the result of `alertThenReturn` (in this case, `innerFunction`):

```js
function alertThenReturn() {
  alert('Message 1!');

  return function () {
    alert('Message 2!');
  };
}

const innerFunction = alertThenReturn()

innerFunction()
```

Alternatively, invoke the result of calling `alertThenReturn()` immediately for the same effect:

```js
function alertThenReturn() {
  alert('Message 1!');

  return function () {
    alert('Message 2!');
  };
}

alertThenReturn()()
```

Comment: you say it is not possible that just const innerFunction = alertThenReturn() would alert twice with the given implementation of alertThenReturn. but I want you to run it. It will work

Comment: @MarcoMaher The first snippet in my answer alerts once.

Answer (score 0):

Just defining the method itself should not give off an alert, but when you call it in the line:

```js
const innerFunction = alertThenReturn();
```

What's happening is that `alertThenReturn` sends an alert message, then returns your inner function. So when you run

```js
innerFunction()
```

This will give you the output of message 2.